# in C I want to read in line by line from a file a certain way with the end length of the file changing

Tags: c, file-io, io

Ok I need to read information in from a file. I have to take certain parts of the line apart and do different things with each part. I know the maximum and minimum length of the file but I am doing something wrong when I read in the file and then split it up as I am getting really funny values and stuff when I try to compare methods. The maximum length of any line is 80 character.

The format for each line will be as follows: (I will write them in column form as they would appear in a character array)
0-7 _ 9 10-16 _ 18 19-28_ _31-79

spots 0-7 will contain a string(any being under 8 will have blank spaces)
spots 8,17,29,30 are all blank spaces (Marked by underscores)
spots 10-16 will contain a string (again any being under the max length will have blank spaces at the end)
spot 18 will contain a blank space or a character
spot 19-28 will contain another string (Same as other cases)
spot 31-79 can be filled with a string or may not exist at all depends on the users input.

Right now I am using a buffer of size 82 and then doing strncpy to take certain parts from the buffer to break it up. It appears to be working fine but when I do strcmp I am getting funky answers and the strlen is not giving the char arrays I declared the right length.

(I have declared them as having a max length of 8,9,etc. but strlen has been returning weird numbers like 67)

So if I could just read it in broken up it should completely resolve the issue.

I was hoping there would be a way to do this but am currently unsure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have attached the part of the code where I think the error is.

(I know it isn't good to have the size hardcoded in there but I want to get it working first and then I'll get rid of the magic numbers)

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL) /* read a line from a file     */
{
    if (buffer[0] == '.') //If it is a comment line just echo it do not increase counter
    {
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    else if (buffer[0] == ' ' && buffer[10] == ' ') // If it is a blank line print blank line do not increase counter
    {
        printf("\n");
    }

    else //it is an actual instruction perform the real operations
    {
        //copy label down
        strncpy(label, &buffer[0], 8);

        //copy Pnemonic into command string
        strncpy(command, &buffer[9], 8);

        //copy symbol down
        symbol = buffer[syLoc];

        //copy operand down 
        strncpy(operand, &buffer[19], 9);
```

Comment: Show the full code, including `label`, `command` and others definitions. "funky" is suggesting undefined behavior.

Comment: Nothing wrong with hard-coded numbers, unless you know you need greater generality.  Aside from time wasted, bugs get created when you add generality without having use cases to test it.  "Magic numbers" are parameters no one could figure out how to derive.  I don't see that here.

Comment: `else if (buffer[0] == ' ' && buffer[10] == ' ')` is a problem.  At this point, code does not know the length of `buffer`, so `buffer[10]` may reference the previous lines value.

Answer (score 0):

Funky characters and overlong string lengths are a sign that the strings aren't null-terminated, as C (or at least most of C's library functions) expects them.

`strncpy` will yield null-terminated strings only if the buffer is greater than the length of the source string. In your case, you want to copy substrings out of the middle of a string, so your strings won't have the null terminator.

You could add the null-terminator by hand:

```
char label[9];

strncpy(label, &buffer[0], 8);
label[8] = '\0';
```

But given that you have spaces after the substrings you want anyway, you could also use `strtok`'s approach to make your substrings pointers into the line you have read and overwrite the spaces with the null character:

```
char *label;
char *command;

label = &buffer[0];
buffer[8] = '\0';

command = &buffer[9];
buffer[9 + 8] = '\0';
```

This approach has the advantage that you don't need extra memory for the substrings. It has the drawback that your substrings will become invalid when you read the next line. If your substrings don't "live" long enough, that approach might be good for you.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: `strncpy` function do not add any null termination(`\0`) at the end of the copied chars.
To protect the target char array you have to manually add a `\0`after each `strncpy`call like this:

```
    //copy label down
    strncpy(label, &buffer[0], 8);
    label[8]='\0';

    //copy Pnemonic into command string
    strncpy(command, &buffer[9], 8);
    command[8]='\0';

    //copy symbol down
    symbol = buffer[syLoc]; //Ok just a single char

    //copy operand down 
    strncpy(operand, &buffer[19], 9);
    operand[9]='\0';
```

If no '\0' is added, chars will be read until a '\0' is encountered in the address after the readed char array in the memory (buffer overflow).

Comment: Ok so I should increase my lengths all by one and add the '\0' into each one at the last place? It may sometimes take up the whole space so if I just added it in at the end it could overwrite a final character is why I was saying to increase everything by one.